# Castle Windsor error using log4net in WinForm app

Tags: winforms, log4net, castle-windsor

I've this error using Windsor Castle with log4net in WinForm application.

Error:

```
Could not convert from 'Castle.Services.Logging.Log4netIntegration.Log4netFactory,Castle.Services.Logging.Log4netIntegration,Version=2.5.1.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc' to System.Type - Maybe type could not be found
```

Stack:

```
in Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Conversion.TypeNameConverter.PerformConversion(String value, Type targetType) in e:\OSS.Code\Castle.Windsor\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\SubSystems\Conversion\TypeNameConverter.cs:riga 91
in Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Conversion.DefaultConversionManager.PerformConversion(String value, Type targetType) in e:\OSS.Code\Castle.Windsor\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\SubSystems\Conversion\DefaultConversionManager.cs:riga 134
in Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Conversion.DefaultConversionManager.PerformConversion[TTarget](String value) in e:\OSS.Code\Castle.Windsor\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\SubSystems\Conversion\DefaultConversionManager.cs:riga 162
in Castle.Facilities.Logging.LoggingFacility.GetLoggingFactoryType(LoggerImplementation loggerApi)
in Castle.Facilities.Logging.LoggingFacility.CreateProperLoggerFactory(LoggerImplementation loggerApi)
in Castle.Facilities.Logging.LoggingFacility.ReadConfigurationAndCreateLoggerFactory()
in Castle.Facilities.Logging.LoggingFacility.Init()
in Castle.MicroKernel.Facilities.AbstractFacility.Castle.MicroKernel.IFacility.Init(IKernel kernel, IConfiguration facilityConfig) in e:\OSS.Code\Castle.Windsor\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\Facilities\AbstractFacility.cs:riga 85
in Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.AddFacility(String key, IFacility facility) in e:\OSS.Code\Castle.Windsor\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\DefaultKernel.cs:riga 320
in Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.AddFacility[T](Func`2 onCreate) in e:\OSS.Code\Castle.Windsor\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\DefaultKernel.cs:riga 377
in Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.AddFacility[T](Func`2 onCreate) in e:\OSS.Code\Castle.Windsor\src\Castle.Windsor\Windsor\WindsorContainer.cs:riga 629
in IocWinFormTest.Installers.LoggerInstaller.Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store) in C:\Sviluppo\IocWinFormTest\IocWinFormTest\IocWinFormTest\Installers\LoggerInstaller.cs:riga 18
in Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Install(IWindsorInstaller[] installers, DefaultComponentInstaller scope) in e:\OSS.Code\Castle.Windsor\src\Castle.Windsor\Windsor\WindsorContainer.cs:riga 324
in Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Install(IWindsorInstaller[] installers) in e:\OSS.Code\Castle.Windsor\src\Castle.Windsor\Windsor\WindsorContainer.cs:riga 674
in IocWinFormTest.Program.Main() in C:\Sviluppo\IocWinFormTest\IocWinFormTest\IocWinFormTest\Program.cs:riga 22
in System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
in System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
in Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
in System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
in System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

the code:

```
public class LoggerInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    #region IWindsorInstaller Members

    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.LogUsing(LoggerImplementation.Log4net).WithAppConfig());
    }

    #endregion
}
```

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>

  <log4net>
    <logger name="NHibernate">
      <level value="WARN" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="NHibernate.SQL">
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    </logger>
<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
  <appender-ref ref="trace" />
</root>
<appender name="trace" type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value=" %date %level %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <param name="File" value="Public\Log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <datePattern value=".yyyyMMdd.\tx\t" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="false" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%d %-8ndc %-5thread %-5level %logger %message %timestampms %n" />
  </layout>
</appender>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

I used NuGet to import all packages and interesting story is that I've the same configuration in a web app and there it works!

Can you help me?

Daniele

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you copied the `Castle.Services.Logging.Log4netIntegration.dll` and all other required assemblies to your project's folder?

Comment: I added Castle.Services.Logging.Log4netIntegration.dll and log4net dll manually inside bin folder and the error has gone! 

Both dll are marked "copy local" in the project referendes but it won't copy them to output folder!

Answer (score 0):

Change the target of the WinForm app from the Client Profile to the .Net Framework. log4net depends on System.Web as a support assembly. The answer to my question has more details if you want to stay targeting the Client Profile.

[Why does log4net 1.2.10 require System.Web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281542/why-does-log4net-1-2-10-require-system-web)