# Class library breaks when targeted to .NET 4 Client Profile

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, .net-assembly, class-library

I have a solution of (C#) .NET 4 Client Profile projects in Visual Studio 2012.  Today I tried to add another project, also targeted at .NET 4 Client Profile.  My new project needs to reference a number of other class libraries in my solution, but it fails to do so for each one with this error:

> The currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" does not include "System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which the referenced assembly "log4net" depends on. This caused the referenced assembly to not resolve. To fix this, either (1) change the targeted framework for this project, or (2) remove the referenced assembly from the project.

None of the projects I am referencing depend on `System.Web`, and they are all targeted at .NET 4 Client Profile. In fact, the error pasted above is for [`log4net`](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) which certainly doesn't depend on `System.Web`.

I have cleaned and rebuilt my entire solution multiple times, and have restarted Visual Studio with no effect.  Any ideas as to how I can get my project to build?

One piece of probably useless information that I'll throw out there: When I created my class library project, it targeted to .NET 4.5 automatically, and I later changed it to .NET 4 Client Profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

I installed log4net with NuGet while my project was still targeted at .NET 4.5.  This caused my packages.config file to be written:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="log4net" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Uninstalling and reinstalling all of my packages from NuGet after changing my target framework version caused the packages.config to be deleted, and rewritten as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="log4net" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net40-Client" />
</packages>
```

And now it works.

Answer (score 1):

log4net **does** depend on System.Web.  You may not be using that namespace, but, that library requires it.  There is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281542/why-does-log4net-1-2-10-require-system-web) that talks about how you could remove it if you're willing to build the project yourself.  You could also change the application target as noted in a different [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767253/log4net-with-net-4-0).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info.  How can it be that all of my other projects that are targeted at .NET 4 Client Profile have no problem using `log4net` then?

Comment: Are you sure they are targeting the .NET 4 Client Profile and not the full .NET Framework 4 install?  Aside from that, then my guess would be that the other applications have a System.Web reference in the project.

Comment: It's strange, but they are definitely targeting CP, and not referencing `System.Web`.  I did find the problem, however, though I don't fully understand it (see my answer).  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For me this is what worked: right click your project in the solution explorer -> unload project - > then right click the project and edit yourprojectname.csproj remove the "Client" value in the node TargetFrameworkProfile, so it should look like this:

```
<TargetFrameworkProfile></TargetFrameworkProfile>
```

Reload your project then rebuild, and that should solve the problem