# The type or namespace name could not be found in AssemblyInfo.cs

Tags: c#

I got the compile error 'The type or namespace name 'log4net' could not be found in AssemblyInfo.cs'

What does this error mean and how do I start going about solving it?

This is the offending line in the AssemblyInfo.cs file

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "Log4Net.config", Watch = true)]
```

I just download a new project and ran into this error on the compile. How does an entry like this even get added to this file?

Comment: My guess is that at some point the project had a reference to `log4net` and you're missing that assembly in the download.

Comment: Strangely, each project builds on it's own, it's only when I rebuild the solution that I get the error. Apparently little elves fixed the problem while I was away last night, because after a fresh get from source control this morning the problem went away. I'm still trying to track down what has changed that made the issue go away.

Answer (score 8):

Right click on your project in the solution explorer and click **Add Reference**

A window will pop up and you should be able to click on a **browse** tab.

navigate to wherever your `log4net.dll` file is, and select that as the reference.

If you don't have a log4net.dll, you can download log4net from [This page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log4net-Tutorial)

Comment: Perhaps better to go to the source for the download: https://logging.apache.org/log4net/download_log4net.cgi

Answer (score 1):

For this issue I was able to fix it by changing Target Framework from : `.NET Framework 4 Client Profile`, to `.NET Framework 4.5`

For the same I found below article :

[How to solve: The type or namespace name ‘log4net’ could not be found in .NET 4.0?](https://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/2011/12/14/how-to-solve-the-type-or-namespace-name-log4net-could-not-be-found-in-net-4-0/)

Comment: In my case updating the calling project from `.NET Framework 4.0` to `.NET Framework 4.7.2` made this log4net issue disappear.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add a reference to the log4net.dll in the 'references'-folder of your project

Answer (score 0):

More than likely you have the wrong profile for the version of log4net.dll.

This warning may be accompanied with that error:

> Warning   3   The currently targeted framework
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" does not include
>   "System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which the referenced assembly
>   "log4net" depends on. This caused the referenced assembly to not
>   resolve. To fix this, either (1) change the targeted framework for
>   this project, or (2) remove the referenced assembly from the
>   project.  CSTestLog4Net

Note: System.Web is not in the client profile (which is default for some new project types) so a non-client profile is needed to run it.

See this thread for more details: [Why does log4net 1.2.10 require System.Web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281542/why-does-log4net-1-2-10-require-system-web)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after installed log4net, whats worked for me was

1. Clean the solution
2. Rebuild Solution
3. Close Visual Studio
4. Open the solution again